# Invertible pseudo-random permutation function

Tags: functions, permutations, computational-complexity, random

We are searching for the permutation function $P_{n,s}(i)$ that computes the $i$th value of an $n$-length permutation ($n,s,i \in N, ~ i < n$) (without storing the entire ordered array), and its inverse $P^{-1}_{n,s}(i)$, with the following requirements:

1. both functions are fast (ideally with $O(1)$ or $O(\log n)$ time and space complexity)
2. for different values of the meta parameter $s$, we get different permutations (like a seed)
3. the permutation is random-like (quality randomness is a nice-to-have, but not required)

The first requirement is simply satisfied by the identity permutation: $P_{n,s}(i) := i$.

The first two requirements are satisfiable, for example, with "mirroring" $s$-sized blocks:

$$
P_{n,s}(i) :=
\begin{cases}
i+s-1-(i \mod s) & \mbox{if } i < n \div s \\
\mbox{(some recursion...)} & \mbox{else}
\end{cases}
$$

For example ($s = 3$):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \cdots \\
2 & 1 & 0 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 8 & \cdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(Then, we can combine a lot of similar tricks for achieving more mix-up, but we still far from which could be called random.)

Is there an efficient method for independently calculating the values of a random permutation?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may have better luck at Stack Exchange's "computer science" site https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you're right, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptography is our friend, [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) is a suitable solution to the above problem. For example, a k-bit [block cipher algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) can act as a reversible permutation for $n_u = 2^k$. For any $n ~~ (2^{k-1} \lt n \le 2^k = n_u)$ we can compute the value with cycle walking.